# Ayuden a editar esta pregunta para que sea aceptable, por favor

Tags: soporte, preguntas, ediciones

La pregunta [¿Son "it", "fun" y "oc" palabras en español?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20812/9385) es, para mí, la más importante que he visto en este sitio desde que empecé a participar, porque los juegos de palabras son divertidos, y le ayudan mucho a uno a mantener el idioma fresco y al día.

¿Cómo se puede plantear la pregunta, con tal de que quede abierta, y que consiga buena respuesta?

Me gustaría poner un bounty si no recibe buena respuesta, pero para eso tiene que quedar abierta.

Comment: Edítala destacando lo que consideras importante. Mira [ask] e intenta eliminar los elementos que chirríen. Actualmente está pidiendo recursos, por lo que lo indicado sería moverla aquí a Meta.

Comment: @fedorqui - El problema con Meta es que tiene muy poco tráfico.  // ¿Se podría hacer algo como el [tag](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) o la [pregunta](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/32159/112436)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como se ve en las [revisiones a la pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/20812/revisions), esto se consiguió en buena manera hasta dejarlo en algo más contestable.

Nótese también que en [Words With Friends Rulebook](https://zyngasupport.helpshift.com/a/words-with-friends/?l=en&s=game-guides&f=words-with-friends-rulebook-1488949904) se lee:

> Words With Friends uses the Oxford Spanish word lists. It includes Castellano as well as other varieties of American Spanish.